# Beautiful soup parsing functions no longer working

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I wrote a web scraper last year that starts at one random wikipedia page,follows the first link in the first paragraph, and scrapes the next page, repeating this process until the philosophy page is reached. This script is a solution to [this problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Getting_to_Philosophy).

In my script, the code started from a fixed number of random pages and for each one, navigated to the philosophy page, recording the lengths of the paths from start to finish (from the random page to the philosophy page). These lengths were then graphed using matplotlib.

All of the steps of the script were working when I tested it early last year, but when I ran it for the first time since then today, for some reason, the beautiful soup parsing code isn't extracting any links from the body of the article or even extracting any paragraphs to be parsed. ***I haven't changed any of the code since it last worked, and the html tags of the wikipedia page DOM seem to be the same as they were before so could it be that the beautiful soup library changed, or is there something subtle about the wikipedia DOM that may have changed recently?***

The code for the script is below:

```
import sys
import json
from urlparse import urljoin

import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,NavigableString, Tag
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
import scipy.stats

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')


class Crawler:
    """ Class used to crawl wikipedia pages starting from a random article."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.base_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org"
        self.NUM_PAGES_TO_CRAWL = 2
    def get_valid_link(self, curr_response):
        """Takes an html response and returns the first link in the main body of the article."""
        curr_root = BeautifulSoup(curr_response.text,"lxml")
        first = curr_root.select_one("#mw-content-text") # locate main body
        if not first:
            return None
        par = first.find_all("p",recursive = False,limit = 10)
        print par
        heading = curr_root.select_one("#firstHeading").text
        heading = reformat_string('(',heading)
        first_paragraph_found = False
        head_tokens = tokenize(heading)

        # Find which paragraph has the first link
        i = 0
        for i in range(len(par)):
            if par[i].b is not None:
                bold = ""
                for string in par[i].find_all("b"):
                    bold += " " + string.text
                bold = reformat_string('(', bold)
                bold_tokens = tokenize(bold)
                heading_match = check_name_match(head_tokens,bold_tokens)
                if heading_match:
                    first_paragraph_found = True
                if heading_match and par[i].a:
                    break
            if par[i].a is not None:
                anchor = par[i].a.text
                if anchor:
                    anchor = reformat_string('(', anchor)
                    a_tokens = tokenize(anchor)
                    heading_match = check_name_match(head_tokens,a_tokens)
                    if heading_match:
                        break
            if first_paragraph_found and par[i].a:
                break   
            i += 1

        # if none of the paragraphs have a link and article contains only a list
        if i >= len(par)-1 and first_paragraph_found:
            u_list = first.find_all('ul')
            try:
                return u_list[0].li.a['href']
            except (IndexError, AttributeError,TypeError):
                return None
        elif i >= len(par)-1:# Reached article with no main body
            return None

        main_body_idx = i
        stack = []
        # Find the first link before or after parentheses 
        for child in par[main_body_idx].children:
            if isinstance(child,NavigableString):
                if "(" in child:
                    stack.append("(")
                if ")" in child:
                    try:
                        stack.pop()
                    except IndexError: # html malformed
                        return None

            if isinstance(child, Tag) and child.name == "a" and not stack:
                link = child['href']        
                link = reformat_string('#',link)
                try:
                    return str(link)
                except KeyError: # Reached article with no main body
                    return None

    def crawl_to_philosophy(self, start_url,session):
        """Follow the path of each url until the philosophy page is reached and return the path."""
        link_path = []
        # Get first link
        try:
            init_response = session.get(start_url)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e: # bad link
            return None

        init_link = self.get_valid_link(init_response)
        if not init_link:
            return None
        link_path.append(urljoin(self.base_url, init_link))

        # Follow path of links until the philosophy page is reached
        i = 0
        while True:
            if "philosophy" in  link_path[i].lower():
                break
            try:
                curr_response = session.get(link_path[i])
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e: # bad link
                return None 

            curr_link = self.get_valid_link(curr_response)
            if not curr_link or "redlink" in curr_link:
                return None
            new_link = urljoin(self.base_url, curr_link)
            for i in range(len(link_path)):
                if new_link in link_path[i] : # loop found
                    return None
            link_path.append(new_link)
            i += 1
        return link_path

    def find_paths_to_philosophy(self,url):
        """Find paths starting from 500 links."""
        i = 0
        crawl_list = []
        with requests.Session() as s:
            while i < self.NUM_PAGES_TO_CRAWL:
                path = self.crawl_to_philosophy(url,s)
                if path is not None:
                    crawl_list.append(len(path))
                    i += 1
            plot_lengths(crawl_list)


def plot_lengths(lens):
    """Plot the distribution of path lengths."""
    freq = {}
    max_len = 0

    for length in lens:
        max_len = max(length,max_len)
        if length in freq:
            freq[length] += 1
        else:
            freq[length] = 1
    max_freq = max(freq.values())
    bins = range(0, max_len + 1, 2)
    plt.hist(lens,bins,histtype = 'bar',rwidth = 0.8)
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('Path Lengths')
    plt.title('Distribution of path lengths')
    dist_names = ['gamma', 'beta', 'rayleigh', 'norm', 'pareto']

    for dist_name in dist_names:
        dist = getattr(scipy.stats, dist_name)
        param = dist.fit(lens)
        pdf_fitted = dist.pdf(bins, *param[:-2], loc=param[-2], scale=param[-1]) * len(lens)
        plt.plot(bins,pdf_fitted, label=dist_name)
        plt.xlim(0,max_len)
        plt.ylim(0,max_freq)
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')
    plt.show()


# Utility functions used by Crawler class

def reformat_string(char, word):
    """Remove passed in char from a string and convert its characters to lowercase."""
    word = word.lower()
    char_idx = word.find(char)
    if char_idx != -1:
        return word[:char_idx]
    return word

def check_name_match(heading, string):
    """Determine whether or not any part of the article heading is in the string and vice versa."""
    for i in range(len(string)):
        for j in range(len(heading)):
            if heading[j] in string[i] or string[i] in heading[j]:
                return True
    return False

def tokenize(word):
    """Split the passed in 'word' on space characters and return a list of tokens."""
    tokens = []
    curr_word = ""
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] == " " and i == len(word)-1:
            tokens.append(word.strip(" "))
            return tokens
        curr_word += word[i]
        if word[i] == " " :
            tokens.append(curr_word)    
            curr_word = ""
            i+=1
        if i == len(word)-1:
            tokens.append(curr_word)    
            return tokens


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"
    crawler = Crawler()
    crawler.find_paths_to_philosophy(url)
```

**The lines in the script that aren't working seem to be the following:**

```
curr_root = BeautifulSoup(curr_response.text,"lxml")
first = curr_root.select_one("#mw-content-text") # locate main body
if not first:
    return None
par = first.find_all("p",recursive = False,limit = 10)
heading = curr_root.select_one("#firstHeading").text
heading = reformat_string('(',heading)
first_paragraph_found = False
head_tokens = tokenize(heading)
```

## EDIT:

The code wasn't working for any of the random links that were selected, but this one doesn't work specifically for example: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Greek

Comment: Maybe check for changes in the page your are scraping ?

Comment: You seem to have narrowed down where the failure occurs. My instinct would be that wikipedia changed its HTML in the past year (perhaps your scraping relied on a fragile assumption about ordering?). Also look at this as an alternative (which uses an API instead of scrapes): https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia

Comment: You may want to use the [wikipedia](https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/) module that hides the low-level HTML implementation.

Comment: Be more specific. Show the url and the text you're after and you will get help here, otherwise you probably won't.

Comment: @pguardiario It wasn't working for any of the random links that were selected, but this one doesn't work specifically for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Greek

Comment: @PRMoureu The script starts from random pages, but you could look at the link I mention in the post to look at the DOM. I don't have the old versions of the DOMs for the pages I scraped originally so I couldn't really compare to see the difference.

Comment: @BaileyParker I'm still trying to use this script so I just want to see if there is an issue specifically with the Beautiful Soup code.

Comment: @DyZ Does that module have a function that can return the first link of the main body?

Comment: I do not remember. Probably yes, but check the docs.